# How to implement single sign on in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, single-sign-on

Currently I have a login form which opens upon opening the excel workbook and is using basic authentication to validate login credentials from Oracle Fusion. However, now I'm required to implement Microsoft single sign on and I have no knowledge about it. Is it possible to achieve this using SOAP or REST API's?

The code I'm currently using:

````
    Dim vFlag As Integer
    Dim tmpReport As String
    Dim documentID As String
    
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim xmlhtp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    vFlag = 0
    
    Dim xmldoc As Object
    Dim xmlnode As Object
    Set xmldoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmldoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmldoc.async = False
    Dim xml As String
    sURL = Constants.EXT_REPORT_SERVICE_URL
    setStatus ("Calling report ..." & sURL)
    tmpReport = tmpReport & vbCrLf & "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:pub=""http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService""> "
    tmpReport = tmpReport & vbCrLf & "   <soapenv:Header/>                                                                                                                               "
    tmpReport = tmpReport & vbCrLf & "   <soapenv:Body>                                                                                                                                  "
    tmpReport = tmpReport & vbCrLf & "      <pub:validateLogin/>                                                                                                                        "
    tmpReport = tmpReport & vbCrLf & "   </soapenv:Body>                                                                                                                                 "
    tmpReport = tmpReport & "</soapenv:Envelope>"
    
    With xmlhtp
        .Open "post", sURL, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8"
        .SetRequestHeader "soapAction", "validateLogin"
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64.EncodeTextBase64(username + ":" + password)
        .Send tmpReport
    xml = .ResponseText
    If InStr(1, xml, "true", vbTextCompare) Then
        vFlag = 1
    End If
    validateLogin = vFlag
    End With
End Function```
````

Comment: *Microsoft single sign* Not sure what you mean, but could it be something related to [Environ](https://www.codevba.com/office/environ.htm#.YVMAVFUzbcs) ? Check the part "Using Environ to get user info"

Comment: The workbook won't be safer than the weakest link anyways. Adding this will only make it seem safer but it will still be easy to break the VBA code using common methods.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns: > Microsoft single sign ... you missed the trailing "on" ;-) He's after MS SSO. To the OP: you need to provide a bit more context about your IT infrastructure, e.g. do you want to authenticate against your local AD or is your organisation using MS' Office365 services?

Comment: The authentication needs to be done via SAMLv2 against my organizations Azure AD